# Drying up Rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application in Ruby/Rails where I am going to have to connect to a third-party application (Xero accounting) in order to send/pull data. This happens in several controllers thoughout the application. However, whilst the specifics are different, the actual connection is the same, and looks like this:

```
require 'xero_gateway'
xero_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/xero.yml")["testing"]
xero_private_key = "#{ENV['HOME']}/certs/breathehr_xero.key" || ENV["xero_private_key"]
xero_gateway = XeroGateway::PrivateApp.new(xero_config['consumer_key'], xero_config['consumer_secret'], xero_private_key)
```

The next step of the code might be fetch something, like an invoice, as in:

```
xero_gateway.get_invoice('INV-001')
```

Or, in another controller, it might be to create a contact, such as:

```
xero_gateway.build_contact
```

Is there somewhere I can put the connection code so that I can end up just calling `xero_gateway` in each specific controller? It doesn't feel right to be repeating the same code again and again each time I have to authenticate and connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @Dave Newton's answer:

You would create a "provider" class that marries an object factory to some configuration:

File: `lib/xero_gateway_provider.rb`

```
require 'xero_gateway'

class XeroGatewayProvider
    cattr_accessor :default_private_key, :default_consumer_key, :default_consumer_secret

    def initialize(overrides = {})
        @private_key = overrides[:private_key] || self.class.default_private_key
        @consumer_key = overrides[:consumer_key] || self.class.default_consumer_key
        @consumer_secret = overrides[:consumer_secret] || self.class.default_consumer_secret
    end

    def create_private_app
        XeroGateway::PrivateApp.new(@consumer_key, @consumer_secret, @private_key)
    end
end
```

Then you could create a Rails initializer: `config/initializers/xero_gateway_provider.rb`

```
require 'xero_gateway_provider'
conf = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/xero.yml")[Rails.env]
XeroGatewayProvider.default_private_key = "#{ENV['HOME']}/certs/breathehr_xero.key" || ENV["xero_private_key"]
XeroGatewayProvider.default_consumer_key = conf["consumer_key"]
XeroGatewayProvider.default_consumer_secret = conf["consumer_secret"]
```

And to use it:

```
# Using default configs
provider = XeroGatewayProvider.new;
private_app = provider.create_private_app
private_app.get_invoice("...")

# Using overrides
provider = XeroGatewayProvider.new :consumer_key => '...', :consumer_secret => '...';
private_app = provider.create_private_app
private_app.get_invoice("...")
```

**Edit:** Just realized there is no point to instantiating XeroGatewayProvider if it uses class level properties, so I made them defaults allowing you to configure each provider individually.

Also @Gareth Burrows comment on where to put and name the class, I think this would fit just fine in the lib/ directory. See the edits to the post for specifics.

Comment: where would the provider class go, and what would it need to be named?

Comment: Just updated my answer. Hopefully that will answer your question, @GarethBurrows

Comment: thats just awesome. Now I need to go through it line by line until I understand it ;) superb answer, thanks.

Comment: hmm. Cant start the server. Receive an error - config/initializers/xero_gateway_provider.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! (NoMethodError)
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Comment: I've been relegated to .NET development lately, so I don't have a good Ruby and Rails installation to test the code on. You could google how to write a Rails initializer and it will probably give you the answer you need. I'm sure you'll have some other stuff to `require` at the top of the file (maybe `require 'rails/all"`?)

Comment: @GarethBurrows, what does your config file look like? It might have a different structure than what my code expects. Can you update your question with the example YAML file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57285/discussion-between-greg-burghardt-and-gareth-burrows).

Comment: It's all working, great work :). I'd made a typo in typing out the code (which I prefer to do rather than just copying it). working nicely now

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular ruby class in the models folder called Xero or something and do this code in the initializer.

```
require 'xero_gateway'
class Xero
  def initialize
    xero_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/xero.yml")["testing"]
    xero_private_key = "#{ENV['HOME']}/certs/breathehr_xero.key" || ENV["xero_private_key"]
    xero_gateway = XeroGateway::PrivateApp.new(xero_config['consumer_key'],     xero_config['consumer_secret'], xero_private_key)
  end
end
```

And then just call:

```
xero_gateway = Xero.new
```

Another option is to create an initializer in the initializers/ folder.
xero_gateway.rb

And put the initialization code in there. This way it will be parsed only on application startup.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it just about anywhere, including:

1. A utility class used by your actions, or
2. A base action class (meh), or
3. A module included in your actions (meh).

I lean towards a utility class, because:

1. It's easy to instantiate or mock/stub it for testing, and
2. It doesn't make the surface area of your action class any bigger